# Does analytical solution exist for this second-order ODE featuring variable coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my research work I came along the following ordinary differential equation (ODE):

$y''(x) + \alpha(k - x)y'(x) + \alpha y(x) = 0,$

with boundary conditions:

$y(\infty) = 0, \quad y(0) = 1,$

where $\alpha$ and $k$ are constants. I have successfully obtained a solution for the corresponding ODE with slightly different coefficients,

$y''(x)+\alpha  (k +x ) y'(x)-\alpha y(x)=0,$

expressed in terms of the error function (Erf) as:

$y(x)=\frac{(\alpha+x)\sqrt{2 \pi  \alpha }  \left[1-\text{Erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha }{2}} (k+x)\right)\right]-2 e^{\dfrac{-\alpha\, (k+x)^2}{2}  }}{k \sqrt{2 \pi  \alpha } \left[1-\text{Erf}\left( \sqrt{\frac{\alpha }{2}}\right)\right]-2 e^{-\alpha\frac{k^2}{2}  }}$.

However, I am encountering difficulties with this particular equation and would appreciate any suggestions or insights on how to find a closed-form solution.

Comment: *Mathematica* gives a solution that fills nearly two screens.

Comment: Exactly, and that is not what I can deal with.

Comment: But it strongly suggests that the solution is irreducibly complicated and long.  Do you have any evidence it isn't?

Comment: I can't, I feel its monstrous, and try to search for any nicer suggestions.

Comment: @Waqar, what did you try ? Write your efforts and attempts otherwise your post will be closed very soon. Please, read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) in order to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: @Angelo did it.

Comment: @Waqar, you have not written your solution in terms of error function (Erf) yet.

Comment: Great suggestion, seems to work. Thanks @Gonçalo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too long for comments*

If you do not use the conditions, the solution of the differential equatio$$y''+\alpha  (k -x ) y'+\alpha  y=0$$ looks quite simple
$$y=c_1\, \sqrt{2\alpha }  (x-k)+c_2\,\left( e^{\frac{ \alpha}{2}  (x-k)^2}+\sqrt{\frac{\alpha \pi }{2}}\,(x-k)\,\text{erfi}\left(-(x-k) \sqrt{\frac{\alpha }{2}}\right)\right)$$

The monster comes from the conditions.

The second one leads to
$$c_2=-\frac{2 \left(1+ c_1\,k\sqrt{2\alpha } \right)}{k\sqrt{2
   \pi\alpha  }  \, \text{erfi}\left(k \sqrt{\frac{\alpha
   }{2}}\right)-2 e^{\frac{\alpha  k^2}{2}}}$$

Try to work the first condition.